Resolved >= yyyy/mm/dd is filtering out all stories not "In Progress"
Atlassian Cloud JIRA Instance
project in ( Team1, Team2, Team3 ) and issuetype in (Story, Task) 
and ((sprint in openSprints() AND resolved = empty) OR resolved >= 2024-01-01)

This query should give me all stories without a resolution date that are in an active sprint, and all tickets from the start of the year that are resolved. For some reason, it only shows tickets in the active sprint that are "In Progress" and filters out those with other active statuses such as "Testing"
Each part returns the correct set, but together they don't.
I have tried nesting in the filters, AND ( resolved >= 2024-01-01 OR filter = 11839) ORDER BY status ASC
And tried pulling the statuses individually, but only "In progress" shows up.

So I found out that the issues in "In Progress" etc. were not being filtered out. My instance will only show 1000 issues at a time. If I sort by status, it will only sort that 1000, not the entire result of the query. If you export the data/load it into another application, all of the data will be there!

You should be able to accept your own answer (with the check mark at its side). Thus others would see that the issue has been solved.
